# Unable to send a user file to php script on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

On Main page I have  accepted  a  file input i.e.

```
form action = "Results" method = "post"

 input type = "file" name="file_name"

 input type = "submit" value="Upload"

/form
```

On Results page I have written a php code to read its content.

```
?php

$file = $_POST["file_name"];

$fp = fopen($file, 'r');  

if($fp == NULL){

    echo '<h2> File not found !!!</h2>';
}
else {

   $line = fread($fp,filesize($file));
        ...
     }

fclose($fp);

?
```

Well the code runs perfectly on XAMPP but when I try to run it on my website it shows this error .

```
*Warning: fopen(004.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u795370533/public_html/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/runtime.php(42) : eval()’d code on line 439 **File not found !!!***

*Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u795370533/public_html/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/runtime.php(42) : eval()’d code on line 652*
```

I have installed exec-php plugin in my website but I'm unable to figure out the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like

```
1) No any file was uploaded to the temp directory
2) You have to check the upload_max_filesize of your server. (run phpinfo() and check)
3) Just `print_r($_FILE)` to check what is the error?
```